# My jsp/css commands are not taken into account

Tags: jsp, servlets

I made a dao project it was working fine and I decided to switch it using hibernate and annotations but since then I've a problem. My css & jstl are not taken into account.

When I acces the page I create I get this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyN3K.png (image) while I'm supposed to have a form.

Example my connection.jsp:

```
<title>Connection</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="connection">
    <fieldset>
        <legend><b>Connection</b></legend>
            <c:import url="connectionForm.jsp" var="importedData"/>
            <c:out value="${importedData }" escapeXml="false"/>

            <input type="submit" name="btn" class="btn-style" value="submit" />

    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

with its webservlet :

```
import [...]

@WebServlet( name="Connection", urlPatterns = {"/connection"})
public class Connection extends HttpServlet{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final String CONF_DAO_FACTORY = "daofactory";
    public static final String ATT_USER = "user";
    private static final String ATT_ERRORS = "errors";
    private static final String VUE_FORM = "/WEB-INF/connection.jsp";
    @EJB
    private UserDao   userDao;


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/connection.jsp").forward( req, resp );
    }

}
```

Comment: What happens if you remove that space in `${importedData }`?

Comment: nothing, same problem. I don't think it's a mistake in my code since it was working before but more or less something I gotta add so the new server I'm using is using the JSTL lib also...

Comment: for anyone wondering it was a problem with the version used something like that. I don't quiet remember since it's a long time ago